# Apache trailing slash added to files problem

Tags: apache-2.2, security, configuration, exploit

I am having a problem with Apache. What it does is this:
Take /index.php file containing an  code with src set to relative path myimg.jpg, both in the root of my server.
So, www.mysite.com would show the image as would www.mysite.com/index.php.

However, if I access www.mysite.com/index.php/ (with a trailing slash) it does the odd thing of executing index.php code as it would be inside an index.php folder (e.g. /index.php/index.php), thus not showing the image anymore.

This is a simple example that's easy to solve with absolte addressing etc, the problem I am getting from this a security one that's not so easily fixed.

So, how can I get Apache to give a 403 or 404 when files are accessed "as folders"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AcceptPathInfo off" would prevent Apache from mapping a request to /index.php/ to index.php + PATH_INFO of "/".

Comment: Thank you, covener. Is that a .htaccess directive or httpd.conf one?

Comment: It's accepted in either context, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo